# How to match nth occurrence in a string using regular expression

Tags: regex, tcl, regex-greedy

How to match nth occurrence in a string using regular expression

> set test {stackoverflowa is a best solution finding site
>   stackoverflowb is a best solution finding site stackoverflowc is a
>   best solution finding sitestackoverflowd is a best solution finding
>   sitestackoverflowe is a best solution finding site}

```
regexp -all {stackoverflow} $test
```

The above one give **"5"** as output

```
regexp {stackoverflow} $test
```

The above one give stackoverflow as result, here it is matching first occurrence of **stackoverflow** (i.e) stackoverflowa

My requirement is i want to match **5th occurrence** of stackoverflow (i.e) stackoverflowe from the above given string.

Please some one clarify my question..Thanks

Then another one question

Comment: I believe you want to match "the entire word that contains the 5th occurence of stackoverflow" yes?

Comment: The 5th occurance is the last occurance. If they aren't the same thing, then you need something like `/(.*?(stackoverflow\S*)){5}/`, answer in capture group 2. Don't know if any syntax like this is supported in tcl.

Comment: The syntax is supported, but the result is a little unintuitive: the correct match gets stored in the _second_ match variable.

Comment: @sln: for completeness and clarity: the invocation is `regexp {(.*?(stackoverflow\S*)){5}} $test m sm ssm`. This puts the fifth occurrence of "stackoverflow" (leaving out the "e") in the subsubmatch variable (`ssm` in the invocation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
set results [regexp -inline -all {stackoverflow.} $test]
# => stackoverflowa stackoverflowb stackoverflowc stackoverflowd stackoverflowe
puts [lindex $results 4]
```

I'll be back to explain this further shortly, making pancakes right now.

So.

The command returns a list (`-inline`) of all (`-all`) substrings of the string contained in `test` that match the string "stackoverflow" (less quotes) plus one character, which can be any character. This list is stored in the variable `result`, and by indexing with 4 (because indexing is zero-based), the fifth element of this list can be retrieved (and, in this case, printed).

The dot at the end of the expression wasn't in your expression: I added it to check that I really did get the right match.  You can of course omit the dot to match "stackoverflow" exactly.

ETA (from Donal's comment): in many cases it's convenient to extract not the string itself, but its position and extent within the searched string. The `-indices` option gives you that (I'm not using the dot in the expression now: the index list makes it obvious which one of the "stackoverflow"s I'm getting anyway):

```
set indices [regexp -inline -all -indices {stackoverflow} $test]
# => {0 12} {47 59} {94 106} {140 152} {186 198}
```

You can then use `string range` to get the string match:

```
puts [string range $test {*}[lindex $indices 4]]
```

The `lindex $indices 4` gives me the list `186 198`; the `{*}` prefix makes the two elements in that list appear as two separate arguments in the invocation of `string range`.

Comment: I know, right? I made a deal with my kids that one of the days during the week they stay with me, they get pancakes. Which, of course, means I get pancakes too ;)

Comment: What would the list look like if multiple nested capture groups? `{(s(t)(ac)k(overf)(low))(.)}` Or is capture groups allowed?

Comment: You get a cyclic result of the whole match (one of `stackoverflowa` ... `stackoverflowe`), then the first submatch (`stackoverflow` in each case), then the four subsubmatches (`t`, `ac`, `overf`, and `low`), and finally in each cycle one of (`a` ... `e`) (the second submatch).

Comment: +1 I was wrongly assuming that OP really meant last, because you know, sometimes what's put in words isn't what's actually meant ^^;

Comment: That seems kind of do-able. Would it return sub-matches on something like this: `{(.*?(stackoverflow)(.))+}` or just the last match of inner sub-expression?

Comment: @Jerry: True. Going by the question, it was a reasonable assumption that the last match was the one sought after.

Comment: @sln: it returns four elements: the big match from the beginning of the string up to ..."flowe", then the last submatch, then the two submatches from the last submatch. But you know, I'm not tclsh: why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: Sorry, I don't either, just wondering if its engine is of any value in this regard. Apparently, so far, only Dot-Net will record itterative sub-expressions matches in arrays from quantified outer groups. Its no big deal but, Dot-Net won't do recursive calls per-se and PCRE style won't do intermediate captures. Puts the kabash on meaningfull language parsing.

Comment: You can also experiment with passing the `-indices` option to `regexp` so that instead of the string, you get _where_ in the search space the match occurred. Intermixes with `-all` and `-inline`, of course.

Comment: The `-indices` option is useful in reality, but seldom yields a well-readable example (string results are obvious in a way that index pairs aren't), so I tend not to mention it when I answer questions like this. Maybe I ought to.